# CSS trouble, bootstrap - masthead swallowing page

Tags: html, css, dom

There is two issues with my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/zmgRW/

A) the actual html content is hidden because of the position fixed tag on the image.

Namely this piece

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h1>Sticky footer with fixed navbar</h1>
                </div>
                <p class="lead"></p>
                <p>
                    sup
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

B) I would like to produce this effect with the navbar rolling up and then locking!

http://jsfiddle.net/shail/YKaBK/show/

Can anyone help?

Also if there are any problems with my CSS/HTML tips would be awesome!

Comment: Did you mean to link to a fiddle with your code loaded? The second link is good, but the first is just a link to jsfiddle.

Comment: just fixed the link! my bad

Comment: you didn't fix the link at all, it needs to point to your fiddle.

Comment: Ahh, I am terribly sorry. My bad!! It is fixed now (= !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the nav becomes affix it no longer follows the normal navbar CSS styles.
You could give an id to the outer DIV container, and then set this as the `affix' element.
Use CSS to make sure it stays 100% width.

```
#nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%
}
```

[Working Demo](http://www.bootply.com/63937)